# How can I select an image's class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I currently have code like this:

```css
.icones  {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between header">
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="coord" href="">
        <img src="{{ asset('build/menu.png') }}"class="icones">Menu</a>
        </div>
```

I currently seem to be unable to select the image's `icones` class. How can I correct the mistake?

Comment: the class is assigned to img not the a. The text "Menu" is in class coord, not icones.

Comment: but if I want to change the style of the imge i should mention the img class in the css code

Comment: if you want to style a : change coord class css , if you want to style img change icones class css

Comment: my problem is solved thank you

Comment: An `img` doesn't have a color or font-size, so your CSS doesn't really make sense for an image tag.

Answer (score 2):

> It is an incorrect property usage on **img** tag.
>
> You can use the **font-size** and **color** on the text HTML elements like H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,P,span and a .... but the **img** tag is not a text element.
>
> To change the **font-size** and **color** of your **Menu**, you should
>   use the **coord** class setted on the **a** tag.

```css
.coord  {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between header">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a class="coord" href="">
      <img src="{{ asset('build/menu.png') }}"class="icones">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```